# ListView.builder vs ListView.custom - Does ListView.custom have the same optimizations as ListView.builder?

Tags: flutter, listview

I've been trying to understand the difference between these two widget constructors (not sure if that's the right term, I'm new to Flutter).

The way you use them seems to be pretty similar. I'm working through a tutorial and ListView.builder seems to be the way to build long lists efficiently since it only builds what needs to be displayed on screen. Does `ListView.custom` do this too?

This docs for `ListView.builder` state:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView/ListView.builder.html

```
Creates a scrollable, linear array of widgets that are created on demand.

This constructor is appropriate for list views with a large (or infinite) number of children because the builder is called only for those children that are actually visible.
```

For `ListView.custom` it says:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView/ListView.custom.html

```
Creates a scrollable, linear array of widgets with a custom child model.

For example, a custom child model can control the algorithm used to estimate the size of children that are not actually visible.
```

It's not quite clear what the difference is, when to use which, etc. Can anyone give some more insight into these two features?

Comment: Please read https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html attentively to understand the difference between them

Comment: @Alexandro That just says: `The ListView.custom constructor takes a SliverChildDelegate, which provides the ability to customize additional aspects of the child model. For example, a SliverChildDelegate can control the algorithm used to estimate the size of children that are not actually visible.`

Comment: For ex. Creatin paragraph of the same doc.
As far as I understand (I am new in flutter too) listview.builder create list view which can load items lazy( it can be useful when you operate with a big amount of items)  on other hands accordingly to naming listview.custom created to write your own behavior for loading items and so on and so for, It described in the doc which I send you. You can navigate through the code and look closely at how work and what do each of these functions under the hood https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/scroll_view.dart